# Why do I get two values for this variable when forking?

Tags: c, process, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int rc = fork();
    int pid = getpid();
    
    printf("from 1: %d\n", pid);
    if (rc == 0) {
        printf("from 2: %d\n", pid);
        rc = fork();

        if (rc == 0) {
            printf("from 3: %d\n", pid);
        } else {
            printf("from 4: %d\n", pid);
        }
            
    } else {
        printf("from 5: %d\n", pid);
    }
}
```

when I run this code, I get this output:

```
from 1: 5890
from 5: 5890
from 1: 5891                                                                                             
from 2: 5891
from 4: 5891
from 3: 5891
```

1 - why does `1` gets executed twice?

2 - why do I get two values for the variable `pid`?

Comment: 1 - Because you called `fork`. 2 - Because you called `fork`.

Answer (score 1):

Because after the first `fork` you have *two* processes both printing the `1` line: Both the parent and the child process executes that statement.

---

It might be clearer if you also printed `rc` on that line as well:

```
printf("from 1: %d %d\n", pid, rc);
```

With the example pids from the question, the above should print

```
from 1: 5890 5891
from 5: 5890
from 1: 5891 0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

> Why does 1 gets executed twice?

Because `printf("from 1: %d\n", pid);` is executed by both processes, the parent and the child.

The call to `fork()` before creates two different processes (when successful).

---

#### 2.

> Why do I get two values for the variable `pid`?

From the [Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html):

> "`getpid()` returns the process ID (PID) of the calling process."

The value for `pid` is different between the child and in the parent because it are two different processes which call `getpid()` and there is one `pid` variable for each process. The two calls to `printf("from 1: %d\n", pid);` don't refer to the same variable `pid`.

Answer (score 0):

1 gets executed twice because you have no conditional before "printf("from 1: %d\n", pid);".  So, both forked processes from "int rc = fork();" will cause this line to execute.